# How can I convert formatted text on a webpage and in the database to RTF or doc

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, rtf, doc

I have some formatted data that needs to be saved from the web page as a word document or rtf, something ubiquitous so I am thinking RTF. What is the easiest way to save something from .net as rtf? Are there built in tools for this or some plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool like [this](http://cutesoft.net/example/editRTF.aspx) does the trick for manual one-off conversions.

And if you want to do the same thing [programmaticially](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/XHTML2RTF.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the formatting should be left out of the database.  I'd much prefer seeing the data stored in a format-agnostic way.  It might be useful for other purposes, and you can defer formatting choices until the last moment.

Comment: He did not mention a database and you didn't really address his question.

Comment: I inferred it from "save", but you're correct - it could just be written to a file system as a document.

Comment: However, I like your point about not storing formatting if this is going into a database.  If you don't know how the data might come back out, why mark it up before storing.

Comment: I mean save as a file or feed it as a download to browser. I agree it should be stored in db without formatting.